# Edit SOAP request from client at WCF Service end

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a WCF Service. It has two operation contracts say, MyFunction & MyFunction1. I want when a client invokes MyFunction, then MyFunction1 should get fired and serve the request.

I dont want to write this function call in MyFunction. I want something like changing the SOAP request in between... I mean before hitting the SVC I want to edit the SOAP and change the SOAP Body and make the tag from MyFunction to MyFunction1

How can I do this any Idea?

Assumption: the MyFunction and MyFunction1 takes same parameter(s)

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting request. I mean, I suspect it would be possible with some request rewriting and ISAPI cleverness, but it sounds like a major long cut. Perhaps if you explained more detail about your problem and why you need to exchange the functions there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can try to use is [custom IDispatchOperationSelector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/10/wcf-extensibility-operation-selectors.aspx) - implementation of this interface is responsible for selecting method which will be called to serve the request. This should be easier than modifying the message.

If you still want to modify received SOAP you can try to use [custom encoder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/11/09/wcf-extensibility-message-encoders.aspx).